# Why isn't explorer showing this SVG gradient

Tags: internet-explorer, css, svg

I have this website http://www.logtech.co.il

The background for the top menu worked fine. It broke for no apparent reason.
I only changed a few position setting of unrelated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support SVG, you need to use VML for vector graphics in IE.

I believe IE10 supports SVG natively now.

Comment: IE has supported SVG since version 9. I'm not sure why that was a suggested edit but that should really have been a comment, and I rolled it back.